# Screen turns black if charging cell phone is put on top of tower

Tags: hardware-failure

If I place my charging cell phone on top of my tower (metal) my computer screen turns black either directly or after a few seconds. If I remove the phone the screen turns on again, but hangs sometimes and I need to reboot then. The phone is plugged into a plug right next to the plugs of tower and screen. If I place my phone on the desk next to the tower nothing happens.

Does somebody have an idea what's happening here?

Comment: The phone screen turns black or computer screen?

Comment: Make/Model of computer might be helpful.

Comment: Well, I assembled it myself. So there's no model no.

Comment: Does any metallic part of the phone touch the tower when you place it on? Do you have the same issue if you put just a sheet of paper between them?

Comment: What sort of phone/case? How's the screen connected?

Comment: Yes it also occurs with the sheet of paper between. Even if it doesn't touch but comes within ~5cm.

The phone is a Samsung Xcover3. The Screen is connected via Onboard Graphic and HDMI connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The happens due to the issue with grounding. Looks like the ground wire is not connected to the real ground in the wall power socket. That may happen in a cheap power surge protector or due to failures in the power scheme at your place.

You need to make grounding by yourself. You need to attach a wire between the screw of your computer case and same metal plate or a pipe/central heating in the building.

You can find a picture and more details in http://www.affordablecebu.com/load/computer_tricks/how_to_remove_ground_electrostatic_discharge_of_computer_cpu_casing/18-1-0-29578

You can also check http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UX_nXwX_EzU
At around 3:40 he shows a ground wire built into the case.